# Entity not saving the updated record?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a base save changes function but its not working its not returning an error just nothing get's written to the database.

```
    Appointment _appointment = new Appointment();
    int errorCount = 0;

    Patient _patient = new Patient();
    _patient = SourceDal.getPatientByPatientId(txtPatientId.Text);
    _patient.SSN = txtSSN.Text;

    _patient.FirstName = txtPatientFirstName.Text;
    _patient.LastName = txtPatientLastName.Text;
    _patient.Middle = txtPatientMiddle.Text;
    _patient.AddressOne = txtPatientAddressOne.Text;
    _patient.City = txtPatientCity.Text;
    _patient.State = txtPatientState.Text;
    _patient.ZipCode = txtPatientZip.Text;


    _patient.HomePhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    _patient.WorkPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;
    _patient.CellPhone = txtPatientCellPhone.Text;

    if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
    _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    if (rBtnHomePhone.Checked == true)
    _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientHomePhone.Text;
    if (rBtnWorkPhone.Checked == true)
    _patient.ApptPhone = txtPatientWorkPhone.Text;


    _patient.BirthDate = dtBirthDate.DateTime;
    _patient.emailAddress = txtPatientEmail.Text;
    _patient.Race = (int)dpRace.SelectedValue;
    _patient.Ethnicity = (int)dpEthnicity.SelectedValue;
    _patient.Language = (int)dpLanguages.SelectedValue;

    _patient.AlertNote = txtPatientNotes.Text;


    if (dpGender.Text == "")
    {
    dpGender.Focus();
    errorCount = 1;
    lblGenderRequired.Text = "* Gender is required.";

    }
    else
    {
    errorCount = 0;
    lblGenderRequired.Visible = false;
    }
    _patient.Gender = dpGender.Text.Substring(0, 1);




    _patient.PatientID = txtPatientId.Text;
    txtPatientFirstName.Text = _patient.FirstName;
    txtPatientLastName.Text = _patient.LastName;
    if(updateOrSave == false) // IF ITS SAVE NEW GO AHEAD ADD IT TO THE CONTEXT.                
    SourceDal.AddToPatient(_patient);

    SourceDal.SaveChanges();
```

My Source dal is made up of functions which which is inherits context base which has the following

```
public abstract int SaveChanges();

protected int SaveChanges(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext context)
 {
            try
            {
                int i = context.SaveChanges();

                if (i == 0)
                    return 0;

                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("SaveChanges failed.", ex);
            }
}
```

There is no error so dont no what is going wrong i declare SourceDal as such

```
 SourceContext SourceDal = new SourceContext();
```

This is my save cahnges that is on the sourcedal

```
    public  override int SaveChanges()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var myContext = new SMBASchedulerEntities(this.Connectionstring))
            {

                return myContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2**

I have even tried the following and still it has not save the patient record the AddToPaient works fine

```
  public void SavePatient(Patient _patient)
    {
        try { 
            using (var myContext = new SMBASchedulerEntities(this.Connectionstring))
        {

            myContext.Entry(_patient).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            myContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Well clearly you're not calling that method in your first example, as that SaveChanges method doesn't pass a parameter for the context. Pleast post the overridden SaveChanges that you show as abstract.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen have posted i their now sorry about that

Comment: You didn't post the code to your AddToPatient method, but I'm guessing you new up an instance of the context (SMBASchedulerEntities) there as well. So, what is probably happening is your adding the patient using one instance of the context and calling SaveChanges on a different instance of the SMBASchedulerEntities context.

Comment: no its on the same instance of the object

Comment: If you're creating a new context and saving against that, then there are no tracked changes.  What did you expect it to save?  Did you really mean to do something more like `this.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: pleae all see edit 2 of the second method i tried which doesnt work